# how to pass variables to package.json scripts

Tags: package.json

how to pass variables from outside like with `yarn setBranchEnv test123 publish123`

```
{

scripts: {
        "setBranchEnv": "export REPOSITORY_BRANCH=\"$1\" && export PUBLISH_BRANCH=\"$2\" && echo REPOSITORY_BRANCH=$REPOSITORY_BRANCH PUBLISH_BRANCH=$PUBLISH_BRANCH",
}
}
```

When i run

```
yarn predevpublish test123 publish123
REPOSITORY_BRANCH= PUBLISH_BRANCH= test123 publish123
```